# Undo "qemu-img resize hdd.img +100GB" with qcow2

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, libvirt

Oops. I accidentally typed TWICE `qemu-img resize hdd.img +100GB` and now I have an image who thinks it can grow to 340GB on a 300GB disk.

Trying `qemu-img resize hdd.img -100GB` returns :

```
qcow2 doesn't support shrinking images yet
```

Please advice :-)

**EDIT**: `# qemu-img info dev1hdd1.img`:

```
image: hdd.img
file format: qcow2
virtual size: 340G (365072220160 bytes)
disk size: 100G
cluster_size: 65536
Format specific information:
    compat: 0.10
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the lack of shrink support, I believe your only option is to create a new image with the correct size and use `qemu-img convert` to copy the data across